# 4TB Seagate external drive not mounting in OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, mount, exfat

I have a Seagate Backup Plus 4TB external hard drive that I had previously been using with this computer. I recently reformatted this drive as exFAT in order to use it to backup files from my MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013) while I upgraded to El Capitan. I successfully used this drive for about a month with the El Capitan OS and now suddenly it will not mount. I feel the drive spin (continues to spin as long as I have it connected) and I know that the drive is at least being recognized as it is listed when I run diskutil from Terminal. I do not however see it in the Disk Utility app.

I have tried manually mounting it from Terminal (`mount -t exfat /dev/disk2s2 /temp1` but it just says "Resource busy".

Any suggestions on how to get this drive mounting again?

Here's the output from running `diskutil info -all`:

```
Device Identifier:        disk2
Device Node:              /dev/disk2
Whole:                    Yes
Part of Whole:            disk2
Device / Media Name:      BUP BL

Volume Name:              Not applicable (no file system)

Mounted:                  Not applicable (no file system)

File System:              None

Content (IOContent):      GUID_partition_scheme
OS Can Be Installed:      No
Media Type:               Generic
Protocol:                 USB
SMART Status:             Not Supported

Total Size:               4.0 TB (4000787029504 Bytes) (exactly 7814037167 512-Byte-Units)
Volume Free Space:        Not applicable (no file system)
Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

Read-Only Media:          No
Read-Only Volume:         Not applicable (no file system)

Device Location:          External
Removable Media:          No
Virtual:                  No
OS 9 Drivers:             No
Low Level Format:         Not supported
```

---

```
Device Identifier:        disk2s1
Device Node:              /dev/disk2s1
Whole:                    No
Part of Whole:            disk2
Device / Media Name:      EFI System Partition

Volume Name:              Not applicable (no file system)

Mounted:                  Not applicable (no file system)

File System:              None

Partition Type:           EFI
OS Can Be Installed:      No
Media Type:               Generic
Protocol:                 USB
SMART Status:             Not Supported
Volume UUID:              0E239BC6-F960-3107-89CF-1C97F78BB46B
Disk / Partition UUID:    9C622B95-3685-4F4C-ABE9-CA679106C741

Total Size:               209.7 MB (209715200 Bytes) (exactly 409600 512-Byte-Units)
Volume Free Space:        Not applicable (no file system)
Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

Read-Only Media:          No
Read-Only Volume:         Not applicable (no file system)

Device Location:          External
Removable Media:          No
```

---

```
Device Identifier:        disk2s2
Device Node:              /dev/disk2s2
Whole:                    No
Part of Whole:            disk2
Device / Media Name:      Windows_NTFS_Untitled_2

Volume Name:              Multimedia

Mounted:                  No

File System Personality:  ExFAT
Type (Bundle):            exfat
Name (User Visible):      ExFAT

Partition Type:           Microsoft Basic Data
OS Can Be Installed:      No
Media Type:               Generic
Protocol:                 USB
SMART Status:             Not Supported
Volume UUID:              459596C4-502A-3CFA-8A2C-DB189139FF1F
Disk / Partition UUID:    19EE6BD9-7E9B-4000-9942-777E0581A89E

Total Size:               4.0 TB (4000443056128 Bytes) (exactly 7813365344 512-Byte-Units)
Volume Free Space:        0 B (0 Bytes) (exactly 0 512-Byte-Units)
Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

Read-Only Media:          No
Read-Only Volume:         Not applicable (not mounted)

Device Location:          External
Removable Media:          No
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Seagate drive has both USB and Thunderbolt connectors (like mine) try the Thunderbolt one.

I suspect though that your drive's partition tables are corrupted. Try a recovery tool such as [M3 Data Recovery, a very good one](https://www.m3datarecovery.com/mac-data-recovery/external-hard-drive-not-mounting-mac.html) (free if recovered data less than 100Mb, $70 if more). I saw other references to Disk Warrior, which costs about $170, but haven't tried that. Other free tools include ddrescue, which in my experience doesn't work consistently if at all.